# How reporting service store the password of SQL user when connect the data source?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-2012

When we create the datasource in the reporting service, we need to assign the account to connect to that datasource, either windows, sql user.

If we choose sql user, we wonder that where is the password of sql user is stored. Or does it encrypt with any algorithm?

Can I refer to any official document regarding this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The details are stored in the `dbo.DataSource` table. The Username and Password are stored in the `UserName` and `Password` columns respectively and are encrypted, as is the `ConnectionString` column. An end user would not be able to decrypt it, unless they obtained the decryption key used internally by SSRS.